# Поиск секторов принадлежащих телу

Tags: c++, алгоритм, разработка-игр

Есть комната заданного размера, разбитая на квадратные сектора. Размер сектора - степень двойки. Тела представлены в виде кругов. Тела могут быть как маленькие, в таком случае можно принять их за точку, так и достаточно большие. Во втором случае тело может одновременно находиться в нескольких секторах. Основная проблема в том, что тела движутся. Соответсвенно список занимаемых секторов со временем меняется.

Есть более эффективный способ обновления списка занимаемых секторов чем каждый раз искать все сектора заново? В принциппе код в вычислительном плане не слишком сложен - строим AABB прямоугольник соответсвующий кругу, тогда находим сектора принадлежащие ему, не забывая проверять на пересечение с кругом. Что хорошо единоразово при добавлении, не факт что таковое при частых обновлениях. Думается мне, должно быть что-то более эффективное.

Ниже пример поиска (используется при добавлении объекта в контейнер)

```
void Gridmap::add(Cell* cell)
{
  geometry::Vec2D delta(cell->radius, cell->radius);
  geometry::AABB aabb(cell->position - delta, cell->position + delta);
  aabb = clip(aabb);
  uint32_t rowStart = static_cast<uint32_t>(aabb.a.y) >> m_power;
  uint32_t rowEnd = static_cast<uint32_t>(aabb.b.y) >> m_power;
  uint32_t colStart = static_cast<uint32_t>(aabb.a.x) >> m_power;
  uint32_t colEnd = static_cast<uint32_t>(aabb.b.x) >> m_power;
  uint32_t sectorSize = 1 << m_power;
  int32_t y = rowStart * sectorSize;
  for (auto row = rowStart; row <= rowEnd; ++row) {
    int32_t x = colStart * sectorSize;
    for (auto col = colStart; col <= colEnd; ++col) {
      geometry::AABB box(x, y, x + sectorSize, y + sectorSize);
      x += sectorSize;
      if (geometry::intersects(box, cell)) {
        Sector* sector = &m_sectors.at(row * m_colCount + col);
        sector->cells.insert(cell);
        cell->sectors.insert(sector);
      }
    }
    y += sectorSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: я думаю есть смысл проверять не все сектора, а только соседние по стороне с занятыми на текущий момент.